# Unity - Detecting keyboard input

Tags: keyboard, 2d, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to Unity and have been looking up tons of tutorials/guides online. My issue is that for some reason when I use the below code it doesn't detect if the keyboard is clicked. Maybe I am doing keyboard detection wrong. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position;

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) {
            player.x += 0.01F;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input code is correct but still couple of things that are not at right place. First you wrote an initializer (static method) outside any function. Remember when you do it in Unity3d C# then it will always give you a warning/error.

> If you are using C# don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, Instead move initialization to the Awake or Start function.

So first move that sort of lines in either functions.

Second thing you are getting `Vector3` and trying to use it as reference, that means you got a position reference in form of `Vector3` and every change made in that variable will be effective, that is not the case, it won't.

But yes you can do it by getting `Transform` or `GameObject`, they will do it for you.

Third and last thing, you are trying to alter `Vector3` component ("x" in your case ) directly, that'd also not acceptable for Unity. What you can do is either assign position with `new Vector3` or create a separate `Vector3` variable, alter that, then assign it to position.

So after all of these addresses your code should be look like this,

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    Transform player;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.D)) {

            // Remove one of these two implementations of changing position

            // Either
            Vector3 newPosition = player.position;
            newPosition.x += 0.01f;
            player.position = newPosition;

            //Or
            player.position = new Vector3 (player.position.x + 0.01f, player.position.y, player.position.z);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I've modified my code for every direction. :)